# storage on htc desire

Tags: external-sd

Hi I've put a 4gb SD card in my htc desire but when I try to go on my gallery it says theres no external storage device and I can't get my head around it, also when I go into storage on my settings it only shows internal storage and do sent seem to acknowledge theres an SD card there at all, finally I can't get onto my camera because it says the same thing, can someone help me please ?

Comment: Can you access the sd card via a file explorer like Astro? Are you sure that the sd card is fully inserted? Have you tried taking the sd card out and putting it back in? Have you verified with another device that the sd card is functional?

Comment: I've tryed all of them but astro so I'll give that a shot. Also when I try to go on my camera it says please mount USB connection and I wonder If that's got anything to do with it ?

Comment: Hey just tried astro and even that isn't acknowledging my SD card :/ any thoughts ?

Comment: Is your phone connected to a computer?

Comment: No not yet, y ?